# Opencart display Model Code in Search Page

Tags: php, search, opencart

can anyone help?/Advise?

I need to display [echo] the model, product code in the search.tpl page in Opencart, can anybody help?

Has any one done this before?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to change the code in the controller for it to be available to the template.  Since it's bad form to edit core files, the way most people achieve this is to write a vqMod for it.  This is a bigger project than can be answered here.

Comment: This actually is a five minute script, 2 simple changes needed. As cale_b mentioned simply edit the controller and echo it afterwards in the .tpl. only two lines needs to be added.   On the other hand i advise you to actually try it before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below 4 steps.

## Step 1

/catalog/controller/product/search.php

**Find:**

```
'name'        => $result['name'],
```

**Add After:**

```
'model'        => $result['model'],
```

## Step 2

/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/search.tpl

**Find:**

```
<div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
```

**Add After:**

```
<b><?php echo $product['model']; ?></b>
```

## Step 3

/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/search.tpl

**Find:**

```
html += '<div class="name">' + $(element).find('.name').html() + '</div>';
```

**Add After:**

```
html += '<b>' + $(element).find('b').html() + '</b>';
```

## Step 4

/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/search.tpl

**Find:**

```
html += '  <div class="name">' + $(element).find('.name').html() + '</div>';
```

**Add After:**

```
html += '  <b>' + $(element).find('b').html() + '</b>';
```

& then check it in your search page.