# Opencart how to display model value of products in search page

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I am using opencart version 2.1.0.2 and I am trying to display in the search results page the model number for each product.

I have tried the follow varius resolutions that I found on the web and also from stackoverflow questions but nothing worked for me at the end and I beleive that the reason its because that the examples that I followed was in different opencart versions.

One of the solutions that i found is 
[Opencart display Model Code in Search Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039252/opencart-display-model-code-in-search-page)

Can anyone suggest me any other solution that can work with my opencart version?

Comment: what do you want to do... do you want to display the model number in the search page..? or do you want to search product by model number?

Comment: I just want to display the model number on the search page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display Model Number in search results

Open search.php from Catalog/Controller/Product

and search for

```
'name'        => $result['name'],
```

add this after

```
'model'        => $result['model'],
```

Now open search.tpl from catlog/view/theme/default/template/product

and search for

```
    <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
         <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
   <?php } ?>
</p>
```

add after

```
<p>
   <?php if ($product['model']) { ?>
      <?php echo $text_model; ?> <?php echo $product['model']; ?>
   <?php } ?>
</p>
```

Hope this answer might Help you

Comment: I got the error
"Notice: Undefined index: model /catalog/view/theme/theme515/template/product/search.tplon line 135".                                                                                                      
                                                                                                              I have add the code after  <div class="product-thumb maxheight1"> <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"> 
 and

Comment: can you share FTP details?

Comment: sure... where do you want to share the FTP details?

Comment: I have just send you the two files (search.php & search.tpl). Let me know if its ok. Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: Thank you! Finally it works after deleting cache from system/storage/cache and from system/storage/modification       (We delete everything except index.html)